# When is local.xml loaded?

Tags: layout, render, local.xml

I'm having trouble getting my page to render properly.

At `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout,` I have the following **local.xml** file ...

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="magentotutorial/helloworld/simple_page.phtml" />
    </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

At `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/magentotutorial/helloworld` I have the following in my **simple_page.phtml** file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #f00;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

At `app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers` I have the following in my **IndexController.php** file ...

```
<?php

    class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

        public function indexAction () {

            $this->loadLayout ();

            $this->renderLayout ();

        }

    }

?>
```

And lastly (not sure if it matters) at `app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc`, my **config.xml** has the following ...

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

According to the tutorial I'm following, this is supposed to create a blank page with a red background, and a page title of **Hello, World!** when I navigate to `http://<mysite>/helloworld/index/index`.

However, it does not.

My module is registered in my Magento installation, and I have made sure to clear both the **Configuration** and **Layout** caches after each respective upload.

What I get instead of what I am expecting is the normal site, minus any page-specific content. The page title is simply *Magento Commerce*.

My version of Magento is 1.7.0.2, and I have been following along with [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates) tutorial (I know it's old, but it worked well up until this section).

Can anybody point me in the right direction to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

The first answer below is actually incorrect, it does fallback. It works the other way against you - you can't have two local.xml files.

So you would need to check if you already have a local.xml file that is being loaded instead of yours. Locations to check are

app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/**default**/layout/local.xml

Original answer

> The **local.xml** in a theme does not have a fallback mechanism so it
>   will only be loaded from your currently active package/theme.
>
> A default Magento install will have the package/theme default/default.
>   I would suggest trying to place the file into
>
> ```
> app/design/frontend/default/default/layout
> ```

Comment: That did not work. But then again I don't have a default installation. I inherited a fully developed installation from an outside shop. I'm still new to Magento, so where would I find out which theme is currently being used?

Comment: In the back-end you can view your current theme settings under System > Configuration > Design

Comment: Package > Current Package Name and Theme > Default would make up your file location app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/layout